# Android Admob force closin

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have went through all the examples I can find and I am not sure where the error is. My code is the same from another app, I just tried to add the admob into the account.  Here is what I could grab from my logcat.

```
    09-29 13:19:28.026: D/ActivityThread(29906): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
09-29 13:19:28.026: D/ActivityThread(29906): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
09-29 13:19:28.026: D/ActivityThread(29906): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
09-29 13:19:28.256: D/dalvikvm(29906): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 31% free 14739K/21059K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
09-29 13:19:28.346: D/dalvikvm(29906): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 21% free 24914K/31239K, paused 12ms+22ms, total 45ms
09-29 13:19:28.586: I/webclipboard(29906): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42d9ebf0
09-29 13:19:28.617: V/webkit(29906): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42d994a8}
09-29 13:19:28.667: I/webclipboard(29906): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42d9ebf0
09-29 13:19:28.667: V/webkit(29906): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42dc21c8}
09-29 13:19:28.747: V/webkit(29906): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {42e2db50}
09-29 13:19:28.747: I/webclipboard(29906): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@42d9ebf0
09-29 13:19:28.767: I/Ads(29906): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("512CF178FE3E3613A01DC3FBA545BD86");
09-29 13:19:28.897: W/dalvikvm(29906): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41480438)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree/com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:316)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:750)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1914)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5179)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
09-29 13:19:28.897: E/AndroidRuntime(29906):    ... 11 more
09-29 13:19:28.957: I/Ads(29906): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"7723615705340179905","seq_num":"1","slotname":"pub-4235852256372242","u_w":640,"msid":"com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree","hl":"en","gnt":13,"carrier":"311480","u_audio":1,"kw":[],"u_sd":2,"ms":"IV6O237njvDEvF1ofv78lOtjwh57ebkvua5-rxjoFyAyMTipUBB2050GvmOPvdWNPsxLTPq4F1GRW1dJdqubdcv0uviIrWVHoPHn0rAGzh4DUHlSTfXHBcAiMsW5AXD6hn-AafG2QBHLoY5vkpaWhotmzeAq-VRV5udolUxpqQxMj7rfhI9wXn5T8o5ths5UUcLfHFTR4Hd7cKftCJQkbazmOsQrDCu4UGju2VDmS5pZ5ZNbvQePhv9OKQHcbNpRGbTtbU_DMKCU3xjqWiaON4LmdTWjwTii0ahlDwdIgSvJvOh9TUMUeDD_ac3jAhw64hZUFqNNkeuZk5UeJ2XuvQ","mv":"80230011.com.android.vending","isu":"512CF178FE3E3613A01DC3FBA545BD86","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":360,"pt":2,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of your code ? The log says that the error might be in line 73 of your file MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your layout you have the admob under the scrollview instead of under the parent layout. ScrollViews can only host one view and what you really want is for the main part to scroll and then the ad to stay constant on the bottom like a footer.

This is evident based on the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

Comment: I noticed that right after I posted it. I am having trouble getting the ads to place but I had it as a fullscreen app and the admob ad as a header. trying it as a footer now. Thank you for the help

Comment: I get the app to run, still can't get any ads to post visually in the app. it runs without error, so Im not sure where I am going wrong becuase there is no ads test or real.

Comment: @mr.j05hua I would need to see the code, I recommend you post it as a new question as this one is closed

Comment: here is the new posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082336/admob-not-generating-visuals