# Admob not generating visuals

Tags: android, xml, admob, android-tablelayout

My admob banner is not showing up on my screen. it compiles and runs fine. i tried to insert it in several places. I am using it as a footer for the application.  I left the second on commented out so that you could see where the idea was that I was trying to put it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             >
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"
    android:background = "@drawable/background"
     >


<TableLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 >    

    <TableRow>        
    <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="hot enough"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="learned"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="hilbilly"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="rot"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>   
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn73"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#00000000"      
       android:text="nicetry"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn74"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="look bad"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />
     <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn75"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="revenge"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"

    />                 
    <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn76"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="group"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    /> 
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>   
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn77"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="takedown"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
        <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn78"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#00000000"      
       android:text="knock"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />    
       <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn79"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="103dp"  
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#00000000"
      android:text="casket"
      android:textColor="#ff0000"
    />       
    </TableRow>
<!--    <TableRow>
  <com.google.ads.AdView 
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adUnitId="pub-4235852256372242"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 512CF178FE3E3613A01DC3FBA545BD86"
     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     />        
    </TableRow> 
    -->
</TableLayout>      

</ScrollView>
          <com.google.ads.AdView 
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adUnitId="pub-4235852256372242"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 512CF17****************"
     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

```
10-01 23:19:53.294: D/ActivityThread(12826): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
10-01 23:19:53.294: D/ActivityThread(12826): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
10-01 23:19:53.294: D/ActivityThread(12826): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
10-01 23:19:53.474: D/dalvikvm(12826): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 30% free 14739K/20995K,     paused 25ms, total 26ms
10-01 23:19:53.544: D/dalvikvm(12826): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 21% free 24914K/31175K, paused 20ms+6ms, total 44ms
10-01 23:19:53.964: I/webclipboard(12826): clipservice:  android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@435a37d0
10-01 23:19:54.004: I/webclipboard(12826): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@435a37d0
10-01 23:19:54.195: I/webclipboard(12826): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@435a37d0
10-01 23:19:54.205: V/webkit(12826): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler   (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {4359e848}
10-01 23:19:54.325: V/webkit(12826): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {436661b8}
10-01 23:19:54.325: V/webkit(12826): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {4366da58}
10-01 23:19:54.465: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(12826): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-01 23:19:54.525: E/(12826): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
10-01 23:19:54.525: E/(12826): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
10-01 23:19:54.725: I/Ads(12826): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script   src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script> <script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"2377731330464712201 ","seq_num":"1","slotname":"pub- 4235852256372242","u_w":360,"msid":"com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree","adtest":"on","js":"af ma-sdk-a- v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"wi","app_name":"1.android.com.mrj05hua.hanselgretelwhfree","hl": "en","gnt":13,"carrier":"311480","u_audio":3,"kw":[],"u_sd":2,"ms":"xxPCYSmHc43AN0YQtB8lGKj2Nu9vDYWw8gtoq7Hi8wmKf5LNzvuTUqGgNUoYXdWcrBgSfDwLuSWaxYKq3qmQra0A5dPF1rppxBS9U0n05OLIqyXKefZQ-ihaTYaGjnUalp6LbNQUQpeHG6H6w_LhCpzxs_th1Om5ot-JZEA-gN25L-iXBS7DEU4_W-s4eMW3SzqYcvY3FsMLQJtA805-ixUsWHeaesRbxyStEOPWOYi0sujnAJ3zb6LnfwQHC-ZQsx56r4yj-o8bTFg275wd260E6P8aBZ70GskV0IDEijwQWiS9WpK7nx-3l38Ift5ANXbvxPvEZSHNxizH8xAacg","mv":"80230011.com.android.vending","isu":"512CF178FE3E3613A01DC3FBA545BD86","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":640,"pt":2,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
10-01 23:19:55.666: D/WebCore(12826): uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue
10-01 23:19:55.706: I/GATE(12826): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
10-01 23:19:55.776: W/Ads(12826): Invalid unknown request error: Cannot determine  request type. Is your ad unit id correct?
10-01 23:19:55.776: D/WebCore(12826): uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue
10-01 23:19:55.776: I/Ads(12826): onFailedToReceiveAd(Invalid Ad request.)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: Also are you using the latest sdk?

Comment: yes the latest sdk and not sure the screen shot will help but here is the shot. The add should appear under the last row of buttons on the screen. Not sure why it isn't still.

Comment: Can you try removing everything else from your layout and just show the ad, just to isolate the problem?

Comment: What does the log say? It is possible that there were no ads to display which would appear in the logs.

Comment: I tried removing everything, and it constantly found enough errors to not even run the app.  i will post what the logcat is saying if it helps.

Comment: @William I posted the logs which do say there is a problem with the ads. Like wrong ad generated or not found id. Im not sure but I posted the log so maybe you guys can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your adUnitId is incorrect. It should be something like "ca-pub-*******", not "pub-4235852256372242"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adUnitId is incorrect. It should be something like " ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY", not "pub-4235852256372242"

Comment: Thank you I Did have to change that and had to go back to admob just to get the specific code. They really do not list that step at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer

[Admob ad not showing up in emulator or phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951106/admob-ad-not-showing-up-in-emulator-or-phone)

If you are new user in admob it might take couple of days to load actual ads.

Comment: I waited for twenty and thirty min on certain tries becuase I had read that one and figured even running test ads that it would run maybe later or something.